# MQTT or REST for cloud-device communication

Tags: rest, mqtt, iot

I am trying to do an IoT project where a node needs to receive some commands from cloud.
Previously, I made this with MQTT protocol. But searching about other protocols on internet I have found REST, which makes possible to communicate over HTTP. However I have seen that this protocol is more used for getting data (makeing a request to the node and receiving the data from it in the response).
I am very new with this protocol. So, I would like to know if it would also be possible to send commands to the node from the cloud, like in MQTT.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP protocol and thus is based in a Request/Response model and using it for IoT device commands can have its drawbacks:

1. Your Devices will need to be accessible over the Internet and this can be a security compromise when you can have the Device with internet access using MQTT subscriptions but no incoming connections to it are allowed.
2. You will need to have some mechanisms for retrying and handling offline Devices in your cloud application sending the commands.

There is also more overhead on HTTP than MQTT given that MQTT has long lived connections. With HTTP you will waste more power on connecting and disconnection, also the network packets will be bigger than MQTT.

Can you use REST/HTTP for sending commands to Devices? **Yes**. Should you do it? **Probably not, it all depends on your actual Device requirements and capabilities and why are you wanting to replace MQTT.**

Answer (score 1):

An IoT protocol that is similar to REST is [CoAP](http://coap.technology/). If you are thinking about using REST in the IoT context I recommend to have a look at it. If your nodes are always connected/reachable there is nothing that speaks against going in this direction. CoAP is a decentralized service protocol where each node might speak with another node.

MQTT is a publish/subscribe protocol with a central broker. As such your cloud could just send the commands to the broker and whenever the node connects to the broker it will receive the commands. So the node doesn't have to be online the whole time.